# Can I use this Panasonic battery charger in extension?

Tags: voltage, power, battery-charging, charger, charging

In our home, the the sockets are marked 5A. I'm using a Philips extension from the same so it reaches near my desk for my laptop charging.

The extension has written: 6A 250V~ 1500W (Max). So I guess it can handle 1500W power.

[**Here**](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B075DB1F13/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)'s the product (battery charger). And when checked on behind, I saw:

[image]

As you can see on charger image above, if I have 220V supply in my home, the power generated would be **0.3**A x 220V = 66W (because *Input = 0.3A* is written on charger)

Which is much much less than 1500W of extension. **So it should be *safe* to use right or would blast like if you plug a big summer cooler on it?** Or do I need only socket in wall (5A or greater)?

Secondly, if you would see on charger, it's written some maths for **Input** and **Output**. What's the purpose of Output text? Does charger has to do anything with it? Isn't it for batteries only since they output the power to devices?

Note: The purpose of this question is to understand how to evaluate what device/charger will work on the sockets installed on wall and what can also work on extensions. I often face this problem.

Comment: The battery charger draws (a maximum of) 0.3A, which is less than what the extension cord can handle (which is good) and less than what your wall socket can handle (which is also good). The output is what goes into your batteries while they’re being charged (at a much lower voltage) and is not really relevant.

Comment: Yes, it is safe to use it.